# refs/remotes/origin/development' exists; cannot create 'refs/remotes/origin/development/master' --tags pushed to all branches

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have created a new repository in bitbucket.

From my local folder  I did:

```
git remote add origin https://......
git push -u origin master
```

So, my project uploaded to bitbucket.

Then, from bitbucket I created 2 more branches , development and release.

I then did:

```
git fetch origin development
```

then `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/development` because I want to push on the development branch.

```
git status -sb
## master...origin/development
```

Then `git remote add origin/development https://..` to add the development branch.

And finally:
`git push --tags origin/development master` to push tags to development branch.

Which , as I saw, pushed the tags in all branches ( master and development), although I selected only development.

Now, the full message from the above command was:

```
Counting objects: 1, done.
Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 170 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://bitb....
 * [new tag]         show -> show
 * [new tag]         v1.0.0 -> v1.0.0
error: update_ref failed for ref 'refs/remotes/origin/development/master': cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/development/master': 'refs/remotes/origin/development' exists; cannot create 'refs/remotes/origin/development/master'
```

So, it says that `remotes/origin/development` exists but `remotes/origin/development/master` not.

I can't understand why it searches for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This step:

> ```
> Then git remote add origin/development https://.. to add the development branch.
> ```

is wrong: it adds a new *remote* named `origin/development`, which is not a good idea since you already have a remote named `origin`.

A remote is simply a short name for a URL at which your Git can contact another Git.  Presumably, all your branches go to the *same* single Git URL on Bitbucket, which you would simply call `origin`.

The `git pull` command makes this especially confusing because it's full of historical oddities.  I recommend avoiding it.  Once you avoid `git pull`—which is merely a convenience shortcut anyway—the remaining items make much more sense: `origin` is simply a short name for your Bitbucket URL, and you `git push origin development` to push `development` there.  When you fetch from `origin`, your Git renames what you get from their Git, so that their `master` becomes your `origin/master` and their `development` becomes your `origin/development`.  The `origin` part here comes from the remote name, and the `/master` or `/development` part comes from the name of the branch as seen in *their* (Bitbucket's) Git repository.

Answer (score 2):

You can also remove ref using:

```
git update-ref -d refs/remotes/origin/development
```